# Mongoose find method does not return array

Tags: arrays, node.js, express, object, mongoose

This is really weird case, but my `Model.find()` method does not return array, instead it returns Objects, not array of objects, just objects. I logged if result was type of Array and it showed false, i've had this kind of problem before and Aggregation method did the trick but it is not now.
this is my code:

```
let docs = await Docs.find({public: true}).limit(5);
const docsToSend = docs.filter(doc => new Date(doc.expires) < new Date().getTime());
console.log(typeof docsToSend === Array)
return res.status(200).send({
    docs: docsToSend
})
```

however i log if docs are array type in client side and it also returns false. I am really confused.What is problem?

Answer (score 0):

That is because, **type of array is object, and not Array**

```js
let arr = [];

let arr2 = [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }];

console.log(typeof arr);   //object

console.log(typeof arr2);  //object
```

**Try:**

```
console.log(typeof docsToSend === "object");
```

```js
let docs = [{field1: true, field2: false}, {field1: false, field2: false}];

const docsToSend = docs.filter((doc)=> doc.field1);

console.log(typeof docsToSend);  //object
```

Comment: well, reasonable. i got confused because i thought this was the cause of my app crashing after X amount of get requests